# Cannot create a directory in the device internal stroage - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was able to create the directory in all the Android devices but now I'm getting an exception stating as `Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed.`

In the project I'm using the dependecies

```
path_provider: ^1.6.27
permission_handler: ^5.1.0+2
```

Have set the **targetSdkVersion & compileSdkVersion** to `30`, added the permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
```

And added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the **application tag** of the `Manifest` file.

flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1165], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (10 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM M025F (mobile) • R9ZR207Z59J • android-arm    • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 93.0.961.38

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Try to reduce the **targetSdkVersion** & **compileSdkVersion** to ```29```

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 9 it’s forbidden to write to internal storage as an app. You’re limited to your own application folder or cache folder. For any specific or extensive info on this you can read more here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` which is required for newer android versions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To get the permission use

```
if (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted) {...}
```

**NOTE:** This permission is considered pretty risky as mentioned by Stjin2210 so play store will reject your app unless it's your app's core functionality.

This is what google says

> Core functionality is defined as the main purpose of the app.  Without
> this core functionality, the app is "broken" or rendered unusable. The
> core functionality, as well as any core features that comprise this
> core functionality, must all be prominently documented and promoted in
> the app's description.

And if you are planning to create a file in an external directory and you are not able to find it, it's because you'd have to tell the device to refresh for the files. So I'd recommend using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner) and passing your newly created file path to it or if you wanna do it manually with kotlin here's the code

```kotlin
    private fun broadcastFileUpdate(path: String) {
        context.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(File(path))))
        println("updated!")
    }
```